# How can i rewrite original url to different URL in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a website developed in asp.net. I want to change URL1 to  URL2 .
I have write a few line of code in my global.asax file.

```
void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("mdu-b.ed-admission-process-eligibility-apply-online-2015-16.aspx", "mdu-b.ed-admission-process-eligibility-apply-online-2015-16.aspx", "~/mdu-b.ed-admission-process-and-eligibility-2015-16.aspx"); 
    }
```

And call this function inside Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) methos like this

```
RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
```

Scenario is; this code working fine but When i Open URL like this (in form of original URL) http://www.ssbedugroup.com/mdu-b.ed-admission-process-and-eligibility-2015-16.aspx it does not open the changed URL i.e http://www.ssbedugroup.com/mdu-b.ed-admission-process-eligibility-apply-online-2015-16.aspx .

Can you guys provide me better solution how could i solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this using IIS's url rewrite module. The following web.config configuration snippet shows how to configure it in order to rewrite your source to the destination url:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^mdu-b\.ed-admission-process-eligibility-apply-online-2015-16\.aspx$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ssbedugroup.com/mdu-b.ed-admission-process-and-eligibility-2015-16.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This effectively configures the web server to return a redirect response each time the source url is requested, so the user is always going to see the destination url in the browser address bar.

Keep in mind that the "match" tag accepts regex for the url, so you need to escape some specially treated characters like dot, backslash, brackets, etc.

Comment: but if i refresh the page http://www.ssbedugroup.com/mdu-b.ed-admission-process-eligibility-apply-online-2015-16.aspx  it shows resources can not be found

Comment: @SoftonicAura Can you elaborate more on what exactly did you do? Have you tried to configure the IIS url rewrite as I suggested?